# How to change default font size in tinymce?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using jquery tinymce editor. Default font size is 10. I like to change that default font size. How can i do that,

Comment: if you're working with django have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47181703/7639622

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to use the [content_css](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/content_css) setting of tinymce to set a custom css file of your own (make sure this setting points to a valid location of a css file). This file will be inserted in the editor iframes head after all other css settings(files from the core) are inserted there when initialising tinymce - thus all settings you place in your file will overwrite the settings made before (by tinymce).

**Example:**  Setting the default font-size to 11px. Content of a custom css file (i named it content.css in my installation):

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

**How to use this setting:**

```
tinyMCE.init({
 ...
 // you do not need to include it yourself, tinymce will do this for you, 
 // but you will need to give tinymce the location of your css file
 content_css : "http://www.myserver.com/css/content.css", 
     ...
});
```

Comment: Where i need to include this css. since my main page also being get affected if i insert in same page. Where to insert this css and how to access it.

Comment: I am sorry to give unnecssary comments. It works for me. I had changed font size in content.css directly, Thank u

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: @Thariama how do you add a dropdown for font size

Comment: @meda: are you using tinyme3 or tinymce4?

Comment: @meda: true, but i saw this just now :) is your problem solved then? :)

Comment: @Thariama  the project was since suspended but I will let you know when it resumes, I do appreciate  your reaching out to me

Comment: however when I am using grunt my CSS will be vanished. This would not work if I am using task runners like grunt or gulp.

Comment: @Thariama This works properly, but i don't get html code for font family & font size when in check this in html editor

Answer (score 28):

I have used in my project in  this way

```
tinymce.init({
  selector:"#txt1",
  setup : function(ed)
  {
    ed.on('init', function() 
    {
        this.execCommand("fontName", false, "tahoma");
        this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "12px");
    });
  }  
});
```

This is the better way than just changing property values in 'content.css'

Comment: this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "12px"); 
did not work for me on tmce 4 with (google chrome 51)
this.getBody().style.fontSize = '12px';
from KwangKungs answer however did.

Comment: Unfortunately this sets the focus to the editor. Can this be avoided?

Comment: @MarioEis there's a fourth argument that receives `{ skip_focus: true }`. This seems to be poorly documented and **not** work as of 6.3.1. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 22):

Just add this line to the options

```
content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}",
```

so it looks like this

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",theme: "modern",width: '100%',min_height:350 ,menubar:false,
     content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;}",
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    plugins: 
    [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
    ],
   toolbar1: " undo redo preview code | \n\
                 link  bold italic underline | hr | image responsivefilemanager media |unlink anchor  | ",
   image_advtab: true ,

   external_filemanager_path:"/tinymce/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host : false,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/tinymce/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
 });
```

Comment: For v3.5 this class worked for me: `.mceContentBody`.

Comment: This was the simplest way of doing it for me in TinyMCE 4.6.1

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
            setup : function(ed)
            {
                // set the editor font size
                ed.onInit.add(function(ed)
                {
                ed.getBody().style.fontSize = '10px';
                });
            },
            });
</script>
```

Comment: second ed parameter is not passed somehow - "this" works

Comment: Seems not to work anymore in 4.6 (whether with ed or this: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ed.onInit.add')

Answer (score 2):

Or just find css file that is used by tinymce and change `font-size`. For example if You using simple theme then go somewhere like this: `js/themes/simple/skins/default/content.css` and there change `font-size`. Working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'll yust leave this here, with tinyMCE 4 it is now:

```
setup : function(ed) {
 ed.on('init', function(ed) {
  ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontName", false, "Calibri");
  ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontSize", false, "11pt");
 });
}
```

Comment: It works, but: If you set f.e. the fontSize to 12 pt and then you press back-delete in a empty editor window it will reset to fontSize 11 (tinymce's default).

Answer (score 1):

A mix of the answers here worked for me:

```
        base_url: '/tinymce',
        suffix: '.min',
        plugins: 'image link lists',
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: 'bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link unlink image | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify',
        branding: false,
        image_uploadtab: true,
        contextmenu_never_use_native: true,
        setup : function(ed) {
            ed.on('init', function(ed) {
                this.getBody().style.fontSize = '12px';
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can also add the font-family with this.getBody().style.fontFamily = 'Proxima Nova Alt';

Answer (score 0):

in `tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/o2k7/content.css` add css:

```
#tinymce {  font-size: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is `content_style` where you can add extra css to the editor.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  content_style: "div, p { font-size: 15px; }"
});
```

Unfortunately you can't just set `body` without `!important` because of the order they set the css.

Also I don't allow people to change the font size - and this will likely go haywire.

This helped me out in changing the 'default' size as viewed, but you need to be cautious if you let people change the font size after this.

For me this quick and dirty approach was all I needed because the HTML I am editing is super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit

tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/o2k7/content.css

and change font-size at this line:

```
body, td, pre {color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; margin:8px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

CSS Path:

> tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css

body{background-color:#fff;color:#000;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;

I changed from 11px to 14ox.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default font size in TinyMCE, you can use `content_css` or `content_style` (or a combination of both) in the initialization script, depending on your use case.

`content_css` can be used to load a specific stylesheet.

For example (where font-size is set on the body element in a file called `mycontent.css`):

```
content_css : '/mycontent.css'
```

`content_style` can be used to tweak (or override) parts of whatever stylesheet the editor is using, regardless of whether that is the default editor CSS or one you’ve specified with `content_css`.

For example:

```
content_style: 'body { font-size: 12px; }'
```

More info and examples here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-change-the-default-font-family-size-and-color-in-tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

Set default font size: Add these options. Working with version: 4.8.5 (2018-10-30)

```
fontsize_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt", 
content_style: "body {font-size: 9pt;}"
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware, TinyMCE inherits font size defined for the parent tag for instance the`<body>` tag

Comment: How to change that explain me.

Comment: @Thariama I think it's obvious

Answer (score -3):

Here's how to do it without any coding

1. Use the plugin 'TinyMCE Advanced'
2. Activate it in settings.

More detailed instructions [here](http://www.theaaronloy.com/enable-font-size-menu-in-tinymce-wordpress-easy/).